# Two Different sized monitors, Same resolution

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a two-monitor setup, and one of them is smaller than the other. So when I use something like Wallpaper engine, the wallpaper doesn't align properly when it extends to both monitors. I don't know if this is a dumb question and may seem like a silly issue, but I was curious to see if there was something I could do about this.

Comment: If the monitors are height adjustable, you can align by changing the height of the monitor.

Comment: @cup - You can align any one part of the image, but not all of it - they're two different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any easy way to resize on just one screen. The computer doesn't know they're different physical sizes (well, strictly it does, but it never really uses that information for such as wallpaper placement).

The simplest method I can think of is for the image on the smaller screen, crop it & re-save, so in effect it is 'zoomed' compared to the larger screen.
You'd probably have to do this by actually measuring the height & relative positions, or just run a couple of variants as trial & error.

You'd end up with something like this pair of images, with the right side being for the smaller screen -

[image]

There's no perfect solution for this, I just think this will be the least jarring visually.

Image © Eberhard Grossgasteiger from https://www.pexels.com/photo/lake-and-mountain-under-white-sky-443446/